# Having runtime error 424 @ Set statement

Tags: vba

I can't seem to get over this hurdle. The errors persists after multiple corrections.

```
Set XlSheet = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
XlSheet.Cells(1, 15) = "Date"

lRow = XlSheet.Cells(XlSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set rng = XlSheet.Range(XlSheet.Cells(2, 15), XlSheet.Cells(lRow, 5)).Select
```

thanks

Comment: take that `Select` off your last line: `Set rng = XlSheet.Range(XlSheet.Cells(2, 15), XlSheet.Cells(lRow, 5))`

Comment: I did but now I am getting a runtime error 438

Comment: what line is throwing that error? try the code in my answer

Comment: For Each cell In XlSheet.rng
             cell.Value = Date
     Next cell

Comment: that `For Each` loop was not in your question code.... Anyhow see edited answer

Comment: thank you. all good

Comment: you are welcome. you may then want to mark my answer as accepted. thank you

Answer (score 2):

edited after OP last comment about the need of a for each loop

`ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet` is useless since it 's the *default* sheet

so you can just code

```
Cells(1, 15) = "Date"
lRow = Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row

Set rng = Range(Cells(2, 15), Cells(lRow, 5))

For Each cell In rng
    cell.Value = Date
Next cell
```

but the whole loop can *collapse* to:

```
rng.Value = Date
```

---

while if you plan to switch over different worksheets then you could code:

```
Set XlSheet = ActiveSheet
With XlSheet
    .Cells(1, 15) = "Date"
    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(2, 15), .Cells(lRow, 5))
End With

rng.Value = Date
```